# CSS 3 animations not working in any browser

Tags: html, css, css-animations

This is a simple website for a school project. I've had trouble with the CSS animation for an image slider at the home page. It refuses to animate, and checking with browser website inspectors show that the rule is not being "computed" (applied?) to the image.

Here is the code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <title>Foo Bar Lorem Ipsum IS-3 | Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets\home.css">
 </head> 
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <header>
    <div id="navbar">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="images\header.png">
   <header>
    <div class="slider">
     <ul>
      <li><img src="images\law1.JPG" width="900" height="675" title="SLC Law 

Workshop"/> </li>
      <li><img src="images\law2.JPG" width="900" height="675" title="SLC Law 

Workshop"/> </li>
      <li><img src="images\law3.JPG" width="900" height="675" title="SLC Law 

Workshop"/> </li>
      <li><img src="images\blood1.JPG" width="900" height="675" title="SLC Blood 

Drive "/> </li>
      <li><img src="images\blood2.JPG" width="900" height="675" title="SLC Blood 

Drive"/> </li>
      <li><img src="images\blood3.JPG" width="900" height="675" title="SLC Blood 

Drive"/> </li>
      <li><img src="images\interview1.JPG" width="900" height="675" title="SLC 

Interview"/> </li>
      <li><img src="images\interview3.JPG" width="900" height="675" title="SLC 

Interview"/> </li>
      <li><img src="images\interview4.JPG" width="900" height="675" title="SLC 

Interview"/> </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </header>
     <div id="main">
      <h1>
       Welcome to the Foo Website
      </h1>
      <hr />
      <p>
       Welcome to the Foo
      </p>
      <p>
       Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
      <p>
       Hello World
      </p>
     </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

And for the CSS:

```
body
 {
  background-image:url("../images/bg.png");
 }
@font-face
 {
  font-family: Interstate;
  src:url("../fonts/Interstate.ttf");
 }
#wrapper
 {
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
  width:900px;
  background-color:#fcfcfc;
 }
#wrapper header img
 {
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
 } 
#navbar
 {
  position:fixed;
 }
#navbar ul
 {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
#navbar li
 {
  display:inline;
  float:left;
 }
#navbar a
 {
  display:block;
  width:225px;
  font-family:Interstate, Segoe UI, sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
 }
#navbar a:hover
 {

 }
#main
 {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding:0;
 }
#main h1
 {
  font-family:Interstate, Segoe UI;
  text-align:center;
  color:#6f273d;
 }
#main p
 {
  font-family:Interstate, Segoe UI, sans-serif;
  text-align:justify;
  margin-left:8px;
  margin-right:8px;
 }
#main hr
 {
  color:#6f273d;
  background-color:#6f273d;
 }
header .slider
 {
  overflow:hidden;
 }
header .slider ul
 {
  width:8100px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:auto;
  cursor:arrow;
  animation: slide 15s;
  animation-duration:15s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-timing-function:ease-out;
 }
header .slider ul:hover
 {
  animation-play-state:paused;
 }
header .slider ul li
 {
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  position:relative
 }
@keyframes "slide"
 {
  0%
   {
    left:0;
   }
  11%
   {
    left:-900px;
   }
  22%
   {
    left:-1800px;
   }
  33%
   {
    left:-2700px;
   }
  44%
   {
    left:-3600px;
   }
  55%
   {
    left:-4500px;
   }
  66%
   {
    left:-5400px;
   }
  77%
   {
    left:-6300px;
   }
  88%
   {
    left:-7200px;
   }
  100%
   {
    left:0;
   }
  }
```

I ran through the whole CSS and HTML file through W3s CSS and HTML validator, but no dice. They don't show any errors. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add -webkit-animation in order for it to work on chrome and  safari.

Answer (score 0):

You need the browser specific prefixes:

```
/*all those who support it*/
@keyframes /*....*/
animation: slide 15s;
animation-duration:15s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-timing-function:ease-out;

/*Chrome and Safari*/
@-webkit-keyframes /*....*/
-webkit-animation: slide 15s;
-webkit-animation-duration:15s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-out;

/*Firefox*/
@-moz-keyframes /*....*/
-moz-animation: slide 15s;
-moz-animation-duration:15s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function:ease-out;

/*Opera*/
@-o-keyframes /*....*/
-o-animation: slide 15s;
-o-animation-duration:15s;
-o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-o-animation-timing-function:ease-out;
```

You can use a tool like compass ( http://compass-style.org/ ) that writes all those vendor specific css rules automatically, you just write:

```
@include transition();
```

Also, this will not work in any browser on earth, refer to the caniuse table: http://caniuse.com/#search=animation

Comment: Brilliant! So these vendor-specific prefixes must be applied to every animation property e.g. -o-animation-play-state, -moz-animation-play-state, so on and so forth?

Comment: Yes, exaclty. Most of the css3 stuff needs prefixes (as for now, this might change in the future)

Comment: Alright, I added the per-vendor prefixes for each animation property, but I still can't get it to animate. Checking with site inspectors for each browser keeps showing that the rules aren't being computed for the image slider. Is there something I'm missing out on?

Comment: that's because you're animating the "left" property, which will only be taken in consideration if the element also has the position set to absolute, fixed, or relative. You're setting it to auto, which means "static". Here's a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/ra2q7/

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by animating the left property. Is the left property the one on my @keyframes properties? I tried replacing them to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding browser prefixes, you need remove the quotes around your animation's name. Note the latest versions of Firefox no longer require the `-moz-` prefix, but you may want to add it any way for those that haven't updated in a long time.

```
@keyframes "slide"
 { ...
```

Should be:

```
@keyframes slide
     { ...
```

You can also save a little time by using the animation shorthand property.

```
animation: slide 15s;
animation-duration:15s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-timing-function:ease-out;
```

Could be:

```
animation: slide 15s infinite ease-out;
```

[See the MDN documentation for CSS animations for further information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)